# Are glycans, such as glucose, considered alicyclic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry

That's my question. If true, it would make my job a lot easier. I will appreciate any feedback on the matter.

Comment: No - oxygen in the ring, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicyclic_compound

Comment: Mithoron you should make your comment into an answer...

Comment: Can you please tell us which job will be easier? We might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3):

Seems I underestimated this problem.

First passage from Wikipedia is crucial:

> An alicyclic compound is an organic compound that is both aliphatic and cyclic.

And second is wrong:

> They contain one or more all-carbon rings(...)

[(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicyclic_compound)

[Glucose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose) is **carbohydrate**, in its circular form which is found in [glycans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycan) (also glucose isn't a glycan, but glucose residue is found in many of them) it has oxygen atom in the ring - according to second passage from Wikipedia it therefore shouldn't be alicyclic, but one can easily find mention about alicyclic ethers for ex. [here](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v68-161), with oxygen in ring. So I'm changing my answer to:

**Yes, they are.**

Comment: Glucose has only one cyclic form, what you called the aldehydic form. It cannot have a hemiacetalic form since it doesn't have a ketone in the open chain. Fructose does have a ketone (but no aldehyde) and makes a hemiacetalic form. `For an aldohexose such as glucose, the C-1 aldehyde in the open-chain form of glucose reacts with the C-5 hydroxyl group to form an intramolecular hemiacetal. The resulting cyclic hemiacetal, a six-membered ring, is called pyranose because of its similarity to pyran. Similarly, a ketone can react with an alcohol to form a hemiketal.`

Comment: The key phrase from wikipedia is "_[Alicyclic compounds]_ contain one or more **all-carbon** rings".  Neither glucose nor fructose qualifies because their ring forms contain non-carbon atoms.  Would you mind editing the answer to reflect this?  I already upvoted you.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I knew from the beginning that this wasn't an easy question, I mean I knew there would be some debate. I am going to discuss this with my colleagues, and I will mention your comments as well. I still haven't made my mind on the matter. It's that oxygen atom on the ring that doesn't convince me about carbohydrates being alicylic.